# VB.Net Loop controls by names using variables

Tags: vb.net, loops, controls

I need to set text of some controls.

I have a `Form` with some `CheckBoxes` an some `TextBoxes`.

In `VBA` (If I have 5 TextBoxes named "TextBox1", "TextBox2", ... "TextBox5") I can use something like this:

```
For n = 1 To 5
    Me("TextBox" & n).Text = NeededValue 
Next n
```

I know that something like this is also possible in `VB.Net` but I wasn't able to find the right syntax (and I didn't find similar codes on SO).

I've tryed using

```
Me.Controls()
```

But I can't insert control name this way

Comment: What if someone decides to use better(more meaningful) control names? That would break your code silently. Don't let your logic depend on control-names.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used "meaningful" control names but I need to show and get valued only some of them (I had no better ideas) suggests are apprecciated

Comment: You could group them in a container control like `Panel` or `GroupBox`. Then it's simple: `Dim myTextboxes=textBoxPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToArray()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter They are already into a panel. I have something like 4 rows. Each one with a ComboBox and five TextBoxes. I need to insert values from a DataTable depending on Datatable.Rows.Count (1 to 4)

Comment: sounds like a DataGridView would be much more appropriate and much easier if the data is in a DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `For Each` and then test with `TypeOf` to find all `TextBoxes` in your `form` like  :

```
For Each myObject1 As [Object] In Me.Controls
     If TypeOf myObject1 Is TextBox Then
         TryCast(myObject1, TextBox).Text = "NeededValue"
     End If
Next
```

Also :

```
 Dim myText = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
        For Each btn In myText
            btn.Text = "NeededValue"
        Next

For i As Int32 = 1 To 5
    Dim Txt = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
    If Txt.Length > 0 Then
        Txt(0).Text = "blah"
    End If
Next
```

Or :

```
  For i As Int32 = 1 To 5
       Dim Txt = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
         If Txt.Length > 0 Then
            Txt(0).Text = "NeededValue"
         End If
   Next
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & n, True)
```

would be the similar approach to your VBA Style.

Comment: I get error when i try to set `Text`. It's not possible to convert `Control()` to `ComboBox` (I used `CType(.Find("CBox_Phase" & r, True), ComboBox)`

Comment: The returnvalue is an array of controls. You have to take the first one and cast it as textbox. I would recommend you to think about your way of handling controls. I don't think it is a good way to iterate over controls by name in general. As I can see you come from VBA I can only suggest you to relearn VB.NET from scratch and forget the VBA things.

And alternative way would be to store all Controls you want to change the text in an List(of Textbox) in your form so you can just do it with for each and the list.