# How to use `Me.Controls("ControlName")` to catch controls into a Panel

Tags: vb.net

I've already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674559/vb-net-loop-controls-by-names-using-variables) on how to loop controls by their names.

Anyway, I've continued searching and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name) with an answer using `Me.Controls`.

I realized that my attempt of using `Me.Controls` failed because the controls (that I was trying to loop) were located into a `Panel`.

If I put them out of the panel I can use `Me.Controls("ControlName")` to catch each control but the panel is really useful and I wouldn't miss it.

Is there a way to use  `Me.Controls("ControlName")` to access controls that are in a Panel?

**EDIT**  (I'm still unable to make it works)
This is my code 
`TLP_Phases` is a `TableLayoutPanel`
`DS_All` is a `DataSet` containing some `DataTables`
Each `DataTable` has from 1 to 4 `rows`

```
For r As Integer = 0 To DS_All.Tables(TblName).Rows.Count - 1
    With Me.TLP_Phases
        Dim CBox_Phase As CheckBox = _ 
            CType(.Controls("CBox_Phase" & (r + 1).ToString), CheckBox)
        'Here CBox_Phase result Nothing
        CBox_Phase.Text = _
            DS_All.Tables(TblName).Rows(r).Field(Of String)("Phase")
        CBox_Phase.Visible = True

        Dim TBox_BasePh As TextBox = _
            CType(.Controls("TBox_BasePh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
        TBox_BasePh.Text = _
            "€ " & DS_All.Tables(TblName).Rows(r)(ProcVal).ToString
        TBox_BasePh.Visible = True

        If DS_All.Tables(TblName).Rows(r).Field(Of String)("Phase").Contains("instruct") Then
            Dim TBox_MaxRedPh As TextBox = _
                CType(.Controls("TBox_MaxRedPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
            TBox_MaxRedPh.Text = String.Format("{0:P}", -0.7)
            TBox_MaxRedPh.Visible = True
            Dim TBox_MaxUpPh As TextBox = _
                CType(.Controls("TBox_MaxUpPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
            TBox_MaxUpPh.Text = String.Format("{0:P}", 1)
            TBox_MaxUpPh.Visible = True
        Else
            Dim TBox_MaxRedPh As TextBox = _
                CType(.Controls("TBox_MaxRedPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
            TBox_MaxRedPh.Text = String.Format("{0:P}", -0.5)
            TBox_MaxRedPh.Visible = True
            Dim TBox_MaxUpPh As TextBox = _
                CType(.Controls("TBox_MaxUpPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
            TBox_MaxUpPh.Text = String.Format("{0:P}", 0.8)
            TBox_MaxUpPh.Visible = True
        End If
        Dim TBox_SelVarPh As TextBox = _
            CType(.Controls("TBox_SelVarPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
        TBox_SelVarPh.Visible = True
        Dim TBox_ValPh As TextBox = _
            CType(.Controls("TBox_ValPh" & (r + 1).ToString), TextBox)
        TBox_ValPh.Visible = True
    End With
Next
```

**I get NullReferenceException** because variables containig controls are Nothing.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `thePanel.Controls(...)` each container control has its own collection

Comment: @Plutonix You can trust me: when I've tryed it it didn't worked! Maybe I've made a typo. Really thanks ;)

Comment: @genespos: Tried *what*?  Didn't work *how*?  "I did something and something wasn't right" isn't a description of a problem.

Comment: It cant not work - the controls have to be in some collection.  maybe you are iterating the wrong panel or controls collection

Comment: @Plutonix I added my code. I think I've done as you suggested or not? Why the code still doesn't work?

Comment: @Plutonix As never said: too much copy/paste and I miss controls names. All works correctly

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the controls in your panel using its `Controls` property.

If you need to get your panel dynamically then do this first:

```
Dim myPanel = Me.Controls("yourPanelName")

For Each ctr In myPanel.Controls
    [do something]
Next
```

Hope that helps. If anything post your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this isn't what I need. See my code (not working) in my edited question.